# Is there such a thing as unary logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

Is there such a thing as unary (as opposed to binary, ternary, …, *n*-ary) logic?

<sup>cf. [Is there any reason for the heavy focus on binary relations in formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/15298/2014)</sup>

Comment: Syllogistic was the "unary logic" ([monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus)), it only admitted one place predicates (attributes). Once two-place predicates are admitted all finite place ones have to be admitted as well since they reduce to them, so we get the standard predicate calculus. Monadic predicate calculus has very poor expressive power in comparison, which is why Kant had to invent synthetic judgments to explain mathematics.

Comment: I see no reason why unary logic would not exist, but it provides no useful purpose/application, to take it beyond just a definition.

Comment: @Guill What would its definition be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a thing as unary logic. I have been working on the subject for years for religious purposes but it's only recently I mastered its demonstrating. It's the logic the bible is built on. It's a one state logic, 1 only ,where zero is unknown.

"Thou shalt not take the name of the LORD thy God in vain ...; Exo 20:7). Here vain translates a word, שָׁוְא shawv which means vanity but also emptiness, falsehood and even false.(Strong dictionary H7723).

Without zero, action cannot be stopped and is therefore everlasting. Genesis 1 states "In the beginning" not at the beginning. Without zero there is no possible cut between minimum and maximum, so its dimension is closed as a circle, and action follows a periodical process; hence the organization in weeks from which nights (zero) are unknown the first seven days.

The Decalogue can be analyzed in such a way. The logic of what is banned is simply out of definition domain, death the limitation of life, covetouness built on I, me, leading to a new state of the Creation.

More generally speaking, new and old testaments are good play fields for unary logic and provide a good set of questions to answer by demonstration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange: Philosophy. :D :D :D  ️